# Carrierwave uploader consuming memory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, out-of-memory, carrierwave

I am using Carrierwave uploader V0.10.0 for my rails project (on RHEL) to upload 310 MB of zip file to server. While the file is being transferred, I could see the server's available memory is decreasing. After the file gets downloaded and when the call returns to the controller to save the uploaded file, I could see the deduction of 3 times (of zip file, say 930 MB) size of memory from available file system space. I am not able to figure out why it is happening.